# App to count total steps taken by a group of people

Tags: tracking, app

I am trying to find an app that can track the total number of steps taken by a group of people.

I want to create a group of friends and set a target number of steps that we need to reach collectively.

However, most of the apps I have found only give individual rankings, rather than the total number of steps taken by the group.

Does anyone know of an app that can do this?

I would appreciate any suggestions. Thank you!